# Print JSON Data in HTML one after the other

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a JSON File with 260 entries and I would like to display each entry one after the other in my HTML Page for 5 seconds. Is that possible?

This snippet print all json data

```
    $.getJSON( "myJSON.js", function( json ) {
     .....
 });
```

Thank you!

My Json file looks like this:

```
[{
                "city": "Los Angeles",
                "name": "Smith"
}, {
                "city": "Las Vegas",
                "name": "Kevin"
}]
```

Comment: could you provide more details about data that will be displayed?

Comment: To expand on @Rafid's comment, do you already know how to display the JSON? what does your data stucture currently look like, is it an array of jsons?

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. But to answer your question: `Is that possible?`, the answer is: `Yes!`.

Comment: @TomosWilliams see my edit on my post

Answer (score 0):

Use setInterval to show different entry every 5 sec.

Answer (score -1):

Following logic should help you:

```js
var json = {"abc":"123", "def":"456"};
m = 0;
setInterval(function(){
    if(m >= Object.keys(json).length) {
        return false;
    }
    key = Object.keys(json)[m];
    item = json[Object.keys(json)[m]];
    console.log(key+' '+item);
    m = m+1;
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I think this helps me out, but I get in the console 0 [object Object]... 43 [object Object] Where should I define my Keys?

Comment: `json` is an array so Object.keys isn’t needed.

Comment: @sokolata - I've edited my response. Run the code and check. This should help you.

Comment: @PramodKumar This is working and shows the defined values, but i need the values from my JSON - File.